# Angular js 1.5 - $injector:modulerr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to duplicate an angular Material example as described on https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete and it's driving me nuts.

I get the following error every time, everywhere (on my machine and JSfiddle)

```
> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=autocompleteCustomT…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)
    at angular.min.js:6
    at angular.min.js:40
    at q (angular.min.js:7)
    at g (angular.min.js:39)
    at bb (angular.min.js:43)
    at c (angular.min.js:21)
    at yc (angular.min.js:21)
    at ee (angular.min.js:20)
    at angular.min.js:313
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:188)
```

The JS fiddle is on this link: https://jsfiddle.net/nicothed/rqv8fLn7

I based it on the blank application on that page: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started#documentation-version.

Would anyone have an idea of what is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work in the fiddle by setting JAVASCRIPT>LOAD TYPE to "No wrap - in < body>", here is the fiddle: [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/rqv8fLn7/1/)

```
<body></body>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you AKMorris and CodeWarrior.

Now, would you have an idea why the dropdown doesn't open when you first click in it? It's supposed to, since   md-min-length="0"

Comment: I think it is because "item" is empty, clicking works after you have data as "item". For example type 'a' in search then delete it, now when you click it will work. My guess is that you need to initialize "item" with data - specifically give "ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" an initial state... i think.

Comment: Yes, but precisely, it should show right away, like in the demo!

Comment: ok on-click autocomplete will not work in material version 1.1.0 you need to use 1.1.4 see it working in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/rqv8fLn7/6/

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Javascript settings wheel in the top right corner of the javascript panel and choose framework as AngularJS and Load Type as 'No wrap - in '[image: Screenshot]